# Android listview: change context menu item depend on item clicked

Tags: android, listview

I need to change list of menu items(actually hide one or just make it not clickable) depending on list item long-clicks.
I asume I can do it somehow in setOnItemLongClickListener but can't find solution:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
......
registerForContextMenu(listView);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View v,int position, long id) {             
            MyListItem item = (MyListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            listView.showContextMenu(); 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found only solution with global variable to set value in OnItemLongClickListener depend on item clicked values and check it in onCreateContextMenu. Also can save there just clicked item (MyListItem). But I think exists more elegant solution.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if(!someGlobalVar){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item, menu);           
    }
    ...
    or
    if(!someGlobalVar){ 
       menu.getItem(0).setVisible(someGlobalVar);
    }
}
```